# Html preloader - delay page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help with my new template :). Before the webpage loads I want to show a preloader gif. I done it, however it shows just a little, because the page loads very fast. So I would like to delay the page (with 2 seconds, as an exemple), without affecting the preloader, so it (the preloader) would appear for 2 seconds, so until the page loads.

Here is my code (note that it will not work on jsfiddle, because I can't upload the .gif file):  jsfiddle.net/hLmxpsnw/

Comment: Wait, are you saying the page loads so fast that you don't really need a "loading..." message, so you want to slow down the loading of the page so much that you will need it? If so, I refuse to cooperate.

Comment: why not just load the page up with a ton of crap so it takes longer to load? or better yet, a Flash intro!

Comment: @Tim don't give him any ideas.

Comment: Mr Lister, yes, maybe you're right. It is a very simple coming soon template with some effects, making for themeforest. I just thought it would look better with a pre loader :).

Comment: A "Loading..." interlude never makes anything better. It's an apology for something being bloated and slow.

Comment: So if the page loads very fast, you suggest me to delete that pre loader ? :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For whatever reason u want it its done using setTimeout here is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            });
        },2000); // set the time here
    });  
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/593Lqqnm/2/

Comment: Note: using jQuery means loading the jQuery library first, instead for something so simple just use pure js. Include the js script and css rules required for the preloader in the head of the html doc. This will ensure a faster load.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Just use delay(); jquery function to add dealy to Preloader**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('#preloader').delay(3000).fadeOut();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a sample

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.loader-container').fadeToggle ();
    },3500);
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.