# Why loader is coming after delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a `div` for **loader** and make it `display: none` default.
And called nested functions. At the start of the first function, I make loader `display: flex`, but it takes approx **1-2 sec** to show loader in Firefox and in Chrome loader is not visible.

I am not able to understand why is this happening?

```
$(".image-lodaer").css({
  'display': 'flex'
});

function generateChatWindow(id, name) {
  $(".image-lodaer").css({
    'display': 'flex'
  });
  $.when(register_popup(id, name)).then(getMessages(id)).then(reloadRecentChat());
}

register_popup(id, name) {
  html appended;
}

getMessages(id) {
  get message from ajax;
  onsuccess $(".image-lodaer").css({
    'display': 'flex'
  });
}

reloadRecentChat() {
  get latest message;
}
```

Comment: the reason is your css/js file loads after html

Comment: we are appending HTML with jquery. So CSS and js should load before appended HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Html preloader - delay page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219587/html-preloader-delay-page-load)

Comment: no I don't want to wait for loader. loader should be displayed when the user clicks on the button.

Comment: what is this button? may you please share the code?

Comment: `function generateChatWindow(id, name) {
    $(".image-lodaer").css({'display':'flex'});
    $.when(register_popup(id, name)).then(getMessages(id)).then(reloadRecentChat());
}

register_popup(id, name){
   html appended;
}

getMessages(id){
    get message from ajax;
    onsuccess $(".image-lodaer").css({'display':'flex'});
}

reloadRecentChat(){
    get latest message;
}`

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24748447) your question and add code in the question itself.

Comment: on click i call generateChatWindow(), inside this function we call 3 functions.