# JavaScript Load a specific image (gif) before anything else

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loading, onload

I have a loading screen for my site and I want the loading gif animation to always be the first image that loads. At the moment it is the last thing that loads. I have left below the HTML and JavaScript. The reason I want to load the gif using JavaScript is so that when the loading screen appears, the gif plays from the start of the animation. I am also unsure if the window event listener needs to be within the document.ready function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/responsive.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/home.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="no-scroll">

    <div class="loader">
        <img src="">
    </div>
```

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    $(".loader").find('img').attr("src", "assets/icons/loading.gif");
    const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
    setTimeout(function(){
        loader.className += " hidden";
        $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
    },2000);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: Does this help - [Delay page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219587/html-preloader-delay-page-load)

Comment: No that just adds a delay before revealing the page which I already have set in place. What I need is for the gif to be loaded first, before any other image is loaded.

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now is to have a display style for img that is based on a css variable.  The variable would be set to "hidden" to start with and your timeout function could just change this to "inline" to show the images

Comment: Unfortunately, this didnt change the order in which the images were loaded into the page, the gif was still loaded in last.

Comment: My workaround for this was built on your idea. I place the image (gif) in the div and set the display:none. As it was as the top of the html file, this then became the first image to be loaded. The javascript then places another image inside the div with the same source which is always visible.